# GitHub OAuth2 Token: How to restrict access to read private repo

Tags: github-api

I checked the following link and there's only scopes for full access of repos. Is there any way I can restrict access to read only?

https://docs.github.com/en/developers/apps/building-oauth-apps/scopes-for-oauth-apps

Comment: The docs already solved it: use the `public_repo` scope.

Comment: @hisam I tried, and the authorization page said I am getting access to "read" and "write" on their public repos.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out if no repo-related scope is provided on creating the token, you will be able to read public repo.

Looks like there is no way to only read public AND private repo at this moment.